# getAllWindowNames() method of DefaultSelenium class not listing names of all tabbed windows?

Tags: selenium-rc

I am writing a sample program to automate the tabbed windows. Please have a look at my sample program:

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;
public class TestTabWindows
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://naukri.com");
    selenium.start();
    selenium.open("/");
    selenium.windowMaximize();
    selenium.windowFocus();

    String window_names[] = selenium.getAllWindowNames();
    System.out.println("--------Window names before any tab window--------");       

    for(int i=0; i<window_names.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(window_names[i]);
    }

    selenium.type("//*[@id='qp']", "selenium");
    selenium.click("//*[@id='search']");

    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("20000");

    selenium.click("//*[@id='1']/strong");      

    window_names = selenium.getAllWindowNames();

    System.out.println("------Window names after tab window is opened--------");        

    for(int i=0; i<window_names.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(window_names[i]);
    }           
}
}
```

Now th problem is that the second for loop at the end of the program should print 2 window names in console - the main window & the tabbed window, but it prints only the main window.

I don't seem to find out why this is happening?

Please suggerst. Regards,

Comment: Waiting for suggestions please.

Comment: No body has responded. Is it that no body knows the fix?

Comment: Could you give the source from the page, particularly behind the button you're clicking to load a new tab?  Sometimes these will show what name is being given to the new window/tab being loaded.

Comment: You are re-using the int "i" twice; in the first instance it has value of 1 so it will have that same value later.  Use "j" for second loop.